# React Native: "BlurView" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, blur

I am getting the below error when trying to implement @react-native-community/blur (https://github.com/Kureev/react-native-blur).

I've tried downgrading from 4.3.0 to 4.2.0 and then 4.1.0 with no success.

Is there a file potentially missing from the node_modules I can just add?

Or is there another library you would recommend using which is compatible with React Native and EXPO

```
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "BlurView" was not found in the UIManager.

This error is located at:
    in BlurView
    in Unknown (created by Post)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View
    in NativeWind.View
    in Unknown (created by Post)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View
    in NativeWind.View
    in Unknown (created by Post)
    in Post (created by HomeScreen)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by ScrollView)
    in RCTScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView
    in NativeWind.ScrollView
    in Unknown (created by HomeScreen)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View
    in NativeWind.View
    in Unknown (created by HomeScreen)
    in HomeScreen (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by BottomTabView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Screen)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Background)
    in Background (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by BottomTabView)
    in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
    in MaybeScreen (created by BottomTabView)
    in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
    in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (created by BottomTabView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by BottomTabView)
    in BottomTabView (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in BottomTabNavigator (created by TabNavigator)
    in TabNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DebugContainer)
    in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
    in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SceneView)
    in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
    in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
    in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
    in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in NativeStackNavigator (created by RootNavigator)
    in RootNavigator (created by App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by App)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the ./node_modules, ./ios/Pods and re-install it all again.

If your Mac's running Apple Silicon chip, use the folling command instead of just pod install:

```bash
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

In case after multiple attemps but it still doesn't work, I suggest using another way to make blurry UI with @shopify/react-native-skia. My project also ultilises this package in creating blurView.
Hopefully my answer might help you.

Edit: I would like to add here my implementation

```js
import {Canvas, Mask, BlurMask, Circle, Rect} from '@shopify/react-native-skia';

const BlurView = (props: BlurViewProps) => {
  const {container, cx, r, blur, styleBlur, color, size} = props;

  return (
    <Canvas style={[styles.container, container]}>
      <Mask
        mask={
          <Circle cx={cx || 65} cy={cx || 65} r={r || 45}>
            <BlurMask blur={blur || 10} style={styleBlur || 'normal'} />
          </Circle>
        }>
        <Rect
          x={0}
          y={0}
          width={size || 130}
          height={size || 130}
          color={color || 'white'}
        />
      </Mask>
    </Canvas>
  );
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: 130,
    height: 130,
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @ndnam198 - I'm using Android. Thanks for the shopify tip will check that out now

Comment: do you have an expo of your project you mentioned about. I'm using Android and docs say you have to ANDROID_NDK=/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/<version> for instance. and I don't quite understand

Comment: Sorry for missing your question, I have added also my implementation